# Linear Regression based on Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statsmodels

I have a df like this:

```
Allotment   Year    NDVI     A_Annex    Bachelor
A_Annex     1984    1.0      0.40       0.60
A_Annex     1984    1.5      0.56       0.89
A_Annex     1984    2.0      0.78       0.76
A_Annex     1985    3.4      0.89       0.54
A_Annex     1985    1.6      0.98       0.66
A_Annex     1986    2.5      1.10       0.44
A_Annex     1986    1.7      0.87       0.65
Bachelor    1984    8.9      0.40       0.60
Bachelor    1984    6.5      0.56       0.89
Bachelor    1984    4.2      0.78       0.76
Bachelor    1985    2.4      0.89       0.54
Bachelor    1985    1.7      0.98       0.66
Bachelor    1986    8.9      1.10       0.44
Bachelor    1986    9.6      0.87       0.65
```

and I want to run a regression based on a groupby.  I want to regress each unique `Allotment` and its `NDVI` value with its associated column. So I want to regress the column `A_Annex` with the `Allotment` `A_Annex` and its associated `NDVI`.  And then I want to do the same thing but with `Bachelor`.  Essentially I want to match the columns with the associated `Allotment` and then regress the values in the column with the corresponding `NDVI` values.

I could do this for one Allotment like this:

```
stat=merge.groupby(['Allotment']).apply(lambda x: sp.stats.linregress(x['A_Annex'], x['NDVI']))
```

but I would need to continue to change the x value in `sp.stats.linregress(x['A_Annex'], x['NDVI']))` and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow why you precede your snippet by "I could do this for one Allotment like this:" - it will do it for each `Allotment` value. I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: Not sure this is the absolute best way, but no real downside to a simple `for` loop here that I can see:  `for x in df.Allotment.unique(): your_regression_code`

Comment: btw, I think the most recommended way to do pandas regressions now is with statsmodels (I added the tag above)

Answer (score 2):

Are you after something like this?

```
r = {annex: pd.ols(x=group['A_Annex'], y=group['NDVI']) 
     for annex, group in df.groupby('Allotment')}
>>> r

{'A_Annex': 
 -------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

 Formula: Y ~ <x> + <intercept>

 Number of Observations:         7
 Number of Degrees of Freedom:   2

 R-squared:         0.3774
 Adj R-squared:     0.2529

 Rmse:              0.6785

 F-stat (1, 5):     3.0307, p-value:     0.1422

 Degrees of Freedom: model 1, resid 5

 -----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
       Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              x     1.9871     1.1415       1.74     0.1422    -0.2501     4.2244
      intercept     0.3731     0.9454       0.39     0.7094    -1.4798     2.2260
 ---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------,
 'Bachelor': 
 -------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

 Formula: Y ~ <x> + <intercept>

 Number of Observations:         7
 Number of Degrees of Freedom:   2

 R-squared:         0.0650
 Adj R-squared:    -0.1220

 Rmse:              3.4787

 F-stat (1, 5):     0.3478, p-value:     0.5810

 Degrees of Freedom: model 1, resid 5

 -----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
       Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              x    -3.4511     5.8522      -0.59     0.5810   -14.9213     8.0191
      intercept     8.7796     4.8467       1.81     0.1298    -0.7200    18.2792
 ---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------}
```

You can then extract the model parameters as follows:

```
>>> {k: r[k].sm_ols.params for k in r}
{'A_Annex': array([ 1.9871432 ,  0.37310585]),
 'Bachelor': array([-3.45111992,  8.77960702])}
```